# PDAL reprojection rendering unexpected results

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, lidar, pdal

I am using a program where a Digital Elevation Model is produced from LiDAR data. The code is written in python 3.8 using the PDAL 2.3.0 library. I have a requirement to update the reprojection from EPSG 3395 to EPSG 4326. When I run the pipeline with EPSG 4326 an all black GeoTIFF is produced with no data. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have attached the JSON data that is being passed in to pdal.

```
dtm_json = json.dumps([file_path,
                {
                    "type": "filters.reprojection",
                   # "out_srs": epsg
                    "out_srs": "EPSG:4326"
                },
                {
                    "type": "filters.smrf",
                    "window": self.window_size,
                    "slope": self.slope,
                    "threshold": self.threshold,
                    "cell": self.cell_size,
                    "where": "(NumberOfReturns > 0 && ReturnNumber > 0)"
                },
                {
                    "type": "filters.range",
                    "limits": "Classification[2:2]"
                },
                {
                    "type": "writers.gdal",
                    "filename": self.output_file,
                    "output_type": "min",
                    "gdaldriver": "GTiff",
                    "window_size": 3,
                    "resolution": 1.0,
                    "data_type": "float32",
                    "nodata": "nan"
                },
                {
                    "type": self.FILTERS_INFO,
                }
            ])
```

Comment: Based on this [lesson](https://pdal.io/workshop/exercises/translation/reprojection.html), I suspect you need to set some more output parameters like cell size or extent. I'm sorry I can't be more helpful, but I've never used PDAL.

Answer (score 0):

`filters.smrf` expects rectilinear coordinates. Put the reprojection to 4326 *after* your SMRF call and you will more likely get the results you expect.